# javascript to typescript on an old file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have found a front-end application here: https://github.com/Clarvel/TennoTyper (the main.js file) and am wondering if I should read what he did and convert it to typescript. Right now I am just importing the javascript file into my scripts in angular.json and is causing a significant slowdown. I wanted to use the code I found to make it into a back-end for my (and my friends) discord server to translate into the different languages of a game with a public API (which I will still need to research how to do but expressJS looks promising).

Tl;dr: Importing JS file in Angular is causing slowdown (high image load count). Should I convert this file to typescript or will this process take too long and be redundant.

Edit: Functionally the app wil work the same way, but it will return an image instead of having to type it in a box on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpiling a exact JavaScript file to Typescript won't help you.

Even you code your application in angular (means typescript)

At the end of the day browser only understands javascript. Your code will be transpiled into javascript when you are building your pacakge.

So find out root cause slowness in the script and fix.

If you are familiar with typescript, do it in that way. Straight conversion without any improvement won't provide any impact.

Comment: I have very limited javascript knowledge, so I think it would be best to convert it. in that case I can have more control about how it works. I didn't mean to transpile directly. I am talking about running through the code and update rather than transpile.

Comment: If you are strong in typescript, just go for it.

Comment: Gotcha, will do that then. Having some classes might also help readability. Since that is a real problem with that file.

Comment: Cool, all the best!